# Port size (8) does not match connection size (4) for port 'A'

Tags: verilog

Can anyone solve my problem with this testbench? It always gives me Z for `sout0` and `sout1`, and I have to mention that during the simulation, Modelsim shows some warnings.

Testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
 module NMA_TB();
wire cout;
wire [3:0]sout0;
wire [3:0]sout1;
reg [3:0] a, b;
reg cin;
NMA #3 nma(a,b, cin, sout0,sout1,cout);
initial begin 
    #5 cin = 1;
    #0 a = 8'b11111111;
    #0 b = 8'b11111111;
    #500
    #0 a = 8'b00000011;
    #0 b = 8'b00000011;
    #500
    #0 a = 8'b11000000;
    #0 b = 8'b10000000;
    #500 $stop;
end 
endmodule
```

NMA verilog:

```
`include "TMA.v"
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module NMA #(parameter n = 3)(input [n+n+1 : 0] A, input [n+n+1 : 0] B, input carry_in, output   [n:0] sum_out0, [n:0] sum_out1, carry_out);
wire [n : 0] w1;
wire [n : 0] s0;
wire [n : 0] s1;
assign w1[0] = carry_in;
assign carry_out = w1[(n-1)/2];
genvar k;
generate
for(k = 0; k < n; k=k+1) begin : NMA_gates
    TMA tma(A[k+k], B[k+k], A[k+k+1], B[k+k+1], w1[k], s0[k], s1[k], w1[k+1]);
end
endgenerate 
endmodule
```

TMA (Two-bit Multiplexer-based Adder) verilog:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module TMA(input a0, b0, a1, b1,cin, output sum0, sum1,cout);
wire cout0;
assign #45 sum0= a0 ? (b0 ? cin : ~cin) : (b0 ? ~cin : cin);
assign #45 cout0= a0 ?  (b0 ? 1 : cin) : (b0 ? cin : 0);
assign #45 sum1=a1 ?  (b1 ? cout0 : ~cout0) : (b1 ? ~cout0 : cout0);
assign #45 cout=a1 ? (b1 ? 1 : cout0) : (b1 ? cout0 : 0);
endmodule
```

And warnings are:

> Warning: (vsim-3015) [PCDPC] - Port size (8) does not match connection
> size (4) for port 'A'. The port definition is at:
> C:/Users/AliZ/Desktop/CA3/NMA.v(3).
>
> Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /NMA_TB/nma File:
> C:/Users/AliZ/Desktop/CA3/NMA_N_TB.v Line: 8 Warning: (vsim-3015)
> [PCDPC] - Port size (8) does not match connection size (4) for port
> 'B'. The port definition is at: C:/Users/AliZ/Desktop/CA3/NMA.v(3).
>
> Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /NMA_TB/nma File:
> C:/Users/AliZ/Desktop/CA3/NMA_N_TB.v Line: 8 Warning: (vsim-3015)
> [PCDPC] - Port size (4) does not match connection size (1) for port
> 'carry_out'. The port definition is at:
> C:/Users/AliZ/Desktop/CA3/NMA.v(3).
>
> Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /NMA_TB/nma File:
> C:/Users/AliZ/Desktop/CA3/NMA_N_TB.v Line: 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum_out0` and `sum_out1` are undriven in the `NMA` module.  You declared them as `output` ports, but you did not make assignments to them.

These changes fix the compile warnings and get rid of Z on `sout1[2:0]` and `sout0[2:0]`.  Refer to the lines marked with `////`:

```
module NMA_TB();
wire cout;
wire [3:0]sout0;
wire [3:0]sout1;
reg [7:0] a, b; ////
reg cin;
NMA #3 nma(a,b, cin, sout0,sout1,cout);
initial begin 
    #5 cin = 1;
    #0 a = 8'b11111111;
    #0 b = 8'b11111111;
    #500
    #0 a = 8'b00000011;
    #0 b = 8'b00000011;
    #500
    #0 a = 8'b11000000;
    #0 b = 8'b10000000;
    #500 $stop;
end 
endmodule

module NMA #(parameter n = 3)(input [n+n+1 : 0] A, input [n+n+1 : 0] B, input carry_in, output [n:0] sum_out0, [n:0] sum_out1, output carry_out); ////
wire [n : 0] w1;
wire [n : 0] s0;
wire [n : 0] s1;
assign sum_out0 = s0; ////
assign sum_out1 = s1; ////
assign w1[0] = carry_in;
assign carry_out = w1[(n-1)/2];
genvar k;
generate
for(k = 0; k < n; k=k+1) begin : NMA_gates
    TMA tma(A[k+k], B[k+k], A[k+k+1], B[k+k+1], w1[k], s0[k], s1[k], w1[k+1]);
end
endgenerate 
endmodule
```

---

`sout0[3]` is still Z, but you need to figure out how it should be driven.

---

As an aside, you should probably use the following syntax (parentheses around the `3`):

```
NMA #(3) nma(a,b, cin, sout0,sout1,cout);
```

IEEE Std 1800-2017 shows the parens as mandatory; I am surprised our simulators didn't generate compile errors.